# Is there a way to mark/tag an excel cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I'm trying to build a C# program that reads data from excel cells. I thought it would quite efficient if I could implement a mechanism that searches an entire excel file and only reads from the cells that have a certain "tag" to it. Is it possible to actually create some sort of tag for excel cells that I can later on reference with C#?

Comment: I can suggest  you a method to create comma separated Smart Tags in Excel Ver. 2010 & higher, also  Formula to Access them, through UDF. Just confirm through comments will it work for you or not? ☺

Comment: If you are using older version like 2003 or 2007 then click **File , Option, Proffing, Auto Correct OPtion &  finally Smart Tag.**

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on conditional rule formatting. That allows you to format cells based on their values or attributes, and can make the cells either look, or behave a specific way based on their current value.

It's a great way to make auto color coding. But the formula for coding this into a C# program would be similar. If "Something" then "Do This".

Conditional Formatting has literally endless options and cell attribute commands, I am sure if you google this function there are non visible tags you enter in.

Another option is right clicking the cell, you can "Add Comment". Perhaps that might be a way to tag cells manually, then have your C# program query any cells with comments.

When searching a sheet or workbook, you can search comments as an option button.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a tag in all cells of an Excel file is very inefficient. What you can do though, is define e.g. a `Range` that consists of the cells you want to read. Then you just traverse the cells in the range in a loop, and read the values.

A range does not have to be contiguos. The cells that belong to a range, can be any combination of cells from a worksheet.

Comment: Inefficient it may be, but this doesn't hope to answer the question, which is not how to find ranges, but how to tag them. There are many other reasons to tag a cell/range.